# Is it still possible to update my iPad from iOS 7.0.4 to IOS 7.1.2 and not to iOS 8?

Tags: ios

Can i upgrade my iPad 2 iOS 7.0.4 to iOS 7.1.2 ? I dont want to install iOS 8. I'm afraid of the performance issues and jailbreak possibilities of my iPad 2 running on iOS 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. It's not possible on any iPad or iPhone because Apple stops signing the older iOS versions after newer ones are released. It's impossible to upgrade to iOS 7.1.2

### Three options you have right now

- Upgrade to **iOS 8.1** [download the firmware separately and update before Apple stops signing]
- Upgrade to **iOS 8.1.1** from iTunes
- Stay on iOS ***7.0.4***

iOS 8.1 has jailbreak, so this could be your chance to upgrade before the window closes.

Comment: IOS 8.1 has Jb but 8.1.1 doesnt, right ?

Comment: @BaranDenizGunduz Yes. That's why I've mentioned about 8.1 separately

Comment: Lots of sources say stay on 7.x.x if you still didnt upgraded to 8. whats your personal opinion on this ?

Comment: @BaranDenizGunduz I don't think it takes any major hit with performance. If that were the case, Apple could have simply not given iOS8 upgrade for the iPad 2.

Answer (score 0):

From anecdotal comments from several friends with iPad2s, the 8.1.1 update did fix some performance issues. One acquaintance who was all set to splurge on a second-hand iPad Air1, installed 8.1.1 and is now very happy that her money can be spent elsewhere.

Apple quite prominently mentions that 8.1.1 fixes performance issues with iPad2, but ArsTechnica actually [published some benchmarks](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/11/ios-8-1-1-iphone-4s-and-ipad-2-a-little-faster-kind-of-sometimes/) and the improvements are mostly minor.

Your milage may vary, however, depending on what you are doing with the iPad.